# Vue Cordova Blank screen

Tags: android, cordova, webpack, vuejs2, babeljs

I have a Vue2 App, when i try to use vue-cordova-cli on mine app for deploy on android's device, it doesn't works and only look a with blank screen, i look for all sites of internet for look the solution with not luck.

I display you the configuration that i have:

- **System Operative**: Windows 10
- **CLI**: Powershell (Administrative Privilege)
- **Android**: 7.1.1
- **Commands npm**

```
   vue add cordova
   npm run cordova-prepare
   npm run cordova-serve-android
```

- **main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

- **vue.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: '',
  pluginOptions: {
    cordovaPath: 'src-cordova'
  }
}
```

More info: All my test are doing using my device connect to my pc using a usb link and i have a lot of deploy previously to that using that way.

Comment: I believe no one say something like "change it and it will work" etc... You really should start to debug your application. On a real device or on an emulator...

Comment: I am using a real device, it can't debug because the vue aplication (#app) can't run. I don't have a complex architecture, the proyect is a hello-world of a vue app and doesn't work...

Comment: this has rather to do with your cordova structure, I guess. I would start by seperately testing: deploying basic html page and working vue page.

Comment: I try that and the problem are the config or the deploy, i don't know -__(..)__-

Comment: If you have an Android device, then you can link it to Chrome - and start debugging. Some instructions can be found by Google-ing (like: https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/using-remote-chrome-devtools-to-debug-android-cordova-apps), and then you'll have more information on what is happening on your device.

Comment: I do that... using remote devices... My app can load because vue app can't load

Comment: I'm having the same problem here. I've tried to start from scratch with the vuetify boilerplate project(only one simple page, and I changed the router mode to 'hash' ). And it works in the browser, but still got me a blank screen when I tried to "serve-ios". My OS: macOS 10.15.1 catalina.